# react scroll to a component without react router and with most basic code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple sections in a web page. Need to scroll to one of the components on button click.
Router of ref is overkill or is not neccessary since it just need to scroll to a section of the page.

Tried this :

```
// on return function
<Button onClick={() =>
                    document
                      .getElementsByClassName("scrollhere")
                      .scrollIntoView() //error not a function.
                  }
                >
                Go to Download Section
</Button>

<Section1/> // Section is equivalent of div 
<Section2/>
<Section3 className="scrollhere"/>
<Section4 id="downloadSection"/>
```

How to scroll at a certain point with most basic code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize the `useRef` hook to refer to an element and then scroll to it.

Something like that

```
const elementRef = useRef();


//Later in the code
<button onClick={() => elementRef.current.scrollIntoView()}/>
<div className="scrollhere" ref={elementRef}/>
```

Read more about `useRef` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)